# A question about the behavior of Dirichlet series and its derivatives

Tags: sequences-and-series, dirichlet-series

Let us consider the Dirichlet series:
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$
We know that its derivative is given by:
$$f'(s)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\ln n) a_n}{n^s} $$

My **question** is: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions in which we get that $f$ assumes **arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values** and its derivative $f'$ is **bounded**.

Comment: I changed ∑_{n=1}^\infty to \sum_{n=1}^\infty since this alters the positions of the subscripts.  Compare $\displaystyle ∑_{n=1}^\infty$ with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$